# PHP Get version from url

Tags: php, regex, url, path, auto-versioning

How can I download the versions from the link? I tried to do it with regEx but it didn't work as I wanted.

I wish it would work like this (Where I gave NULL, there is nothing to choose from)

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js > 1.11.2
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/v1.11.2/jquery.min.js > 1.11.2
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/version-1.11.2/jquery.min.js > 1.11.2
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1-11-2/jquery.min.js > NULL
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1112/jquery.min.js > NULL
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LdBsjgVaoTJ8rC-Npzz16bnAE > NULL
```

My regEx: `/([0-9]+\.?)+/`

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? please clarify your problem.

Comment: @AdisonMasih I would like to get versions from links as shown on the example of several links. I gave the arrow to illustrate what to download from the link

Comment: My current regEx does not work as it needs because it selects every number and not so many which should be because, for example, when I give a link to recaptcha, it selects values ​​from the key and should not return anything

Comment: @Wiktor Answered Your Question Already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
\/(?:v(?:ersion)?-?)?\K\d+(?:\.\d+)+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t9o5sD/2). NOTE: if you want to make sure after the version number there is a `/` or end of string, add a `(?![^\/])` lookahead at the end of the pattern, `\/(?:v(?:ersion)?-?)?\K\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?![^\/])` (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t9o5sD/3)).

*Details*:

- `\/` - a `/` char
- `(?:v(?:ersion)?-?)?` - an optional sequence of a `v` and then an optional `ersion` and then an optional `-` char
  - `\K` - omit the matched text
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)+` - match and consumer one or more digits and then one or more sequences of a dot and one or more digits.